# How to create half-modal view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I don't know what the term for these kind of pop-Ups is and how they can be created. Basically what I would like to have is this kind of pop up from the bottom like in the google sheets application which happens if I push some sort of button for example.

Can I do this directly in the storyboard? What kind of code do I need? Or how exactly is the thing I'm looking for called? Is it a half modal?

[image: here is image 1][image: enter here is image 2]

Or also like in this application 
[image]

Comment: There's no official name or component that I know of for something like this.  It's just custom work.

Comment: Check this : https://cocoapods.org/pods/CNPPopupController

Comment: Also this: https://cocoapods.org/pods/PopupDialog

Comment: Thank you, I looked into those libraries :) in the end I decided to do it with an own subview though and just animated the thing in an out depending on which buttons you click so now it looks very similar :)